# Input 4 number either positive or negative then add all the negative numbers using if else only

Tags: java

How to find the sum of all negative numbers ignoring positive numbers?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        float ans;

        float num = input.nextFloat();
        float num2 = input.nextFloat();
        float num3 = input.nextFloat();
        float num4 = input.nextFloat();

        if (num < 0 || num2 < 0 || num3 < 0 || num4 < 0){
            ans = num + num2 + num3 + num4;
            System.out.printf("%.2f", ans);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input:** -30.22, 10.5, -2.2, -1.8

**Expected Output:** -34.22

Comment: You're trying to do everything in one go.  You have to consider _each input_ number _individually_: if it's negative, add it to the total; if non-negative, don't add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using multiple condition with or operation. In this case even if one number is negative, or satisfies your condition, all the number will be added.

```
if (num < 0 || num2 < 0 || num3 < 0 || num4 < 0){ ... }
```

To add only negative numbers, check each number one by one and perform the summation.

```
float ans = 0;

if (num < 0) {
   ans = ans + num;
}

if (num2 < 0) {
   ans = ans + num2;
}

...

System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Sum {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        float ans=0.0F;

        float num = sc.nextFloat();
        float num2 = sc.nextFloat();
        float num3 = sc.nextFloat();
        float num4 = sc.nextFloat();

        if (num < 0  )
            ans = ans+num;

               if (num2 < 0  )
               ans = ans+num2;

                 if (num3 < 0  )
                 ans = ans+num3;

                    if (num4 < 0  )
                    ans = ans+num4;

            System.out.println("Sum of negative numbers = "+ans);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a simpler code by using for loops:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

float answer = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    float number = input.nextFloat();
    if(number < 0) {
        answer += number;
    }
}

System.out.printf("%.2f", answer);
```